# Programming Zebra Rw-420

Tags: zebra-printers

Could anyone please explain to me different printer modes it has: 
cpcl, line printing epl, ZPL, label printing...?

1. Does each of these modes is designed for certain usage?
2. What is the difference, why are there so many modes?
3. Which mode is the popular one in printing labels, invoices, etc..?

For instance I found that in cpcl language there is a narrow range of fonts available.
in ZPL there are much more, or I can even upload some into device.

In CPCL it is difficult for me to configure the printer to use certain non Ascii characters. I will try to draw text in zpl but don't know if there are disadvantages ..?

Answer (score 0):

The different languages are kept both to keep supporting existing legacy applications and because each mode offers unique advantages:

1. ZPL is excellent for label printing, much like the labels you see on store shelves or shipped packages.  It is a robust language that Zebra offers the widest arrays of support for.
2. Line Print Mode causes the printer to simply print whatever data is received.  This is excellent when printing variable-length receipts.
3. CPCL offers functionality similar to ZPL in what I interpret as a less 'pretty' syntax.  It is sensitive to new line characters and capitalization.

ZPL is likely the way to go for you, especially if you're printing labels of a static length.

Comment: When the Zebra printer is in ZPL mode, after sample print out, it pull the paper out and cannot finish as it gives me the suggestion that it is looking for gap between labels. So is that mean that ZPL mode is designed only for label printing? I need to print out some invoices on long paper ...

Comment: I recommend that you use Zebra's tool Zebra Setup Utilities to configure the printer to continuous media mode.  There are other ways of doing it, but this software is probably the simplest.  You can download Zebra Setup Utilities here: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/manage-software/zebra-setup-utility.html.

Comment: Also, there is a difference in between 'language' being used and 'media detection' being used.  ZPL supports both label media and continuous media, although you typically associate line-print mode with continuous media, but ZPL still works.  Your concern is turning label detection off (that is, putting the printer in continuous mode), and not so much which language is being used.